# How to Count Unique Values with Multiple Conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have several sheets. The relevant sheets are "BookedAppointment" and "No Show" and "Summary".

Whenever a person books an appointment, they are added as a new row in the BookedAppointment sheet.

Whenever a person doesn't show up for an appointment, they are added as a new row in the No Show sheet.

I'm trying to create a summary in cell "Summary!G6", and I want to count how many unique people booked an appointment during the month, didn't show up to that appointment, and then didn't book another appointment afterward.

I use people's email address as the identifier of a person. So I want to count the unique emails that match that criteria.

I'm trying to use an equation like this in my Summary sheet:

```
=COUNTUNIQUEIFS('No Shows'!B:B,'No Shows'!D:D,">"&A5-1,'No Shows'!D:D,"<"&B5+1)
```

But that only counts the unique no shows during the month.

How might I count the emails of the people that {1}didn't show up(so they're in the No Show sheet with a timestamp during the month) and {2} haven't booked another appointment afterward (so they don't have a row in the BookedAppointment sheet with a timestamp after the timestamp on their row in the No Show sheet)?

Any advice or ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[Here's a link to my Google Sheet, so you can see it](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mRl6w2uXzI8HUawYA4SeubH1kiW8p1KUTYvwfxV4FWM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Would an Apps Script solution be acceptable? Perhaps a custom function?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something that works, in a test sheet I made.  But if you provided some more data, and a sample sheet, that would make it easier.  Try this formula in cell 'No Shows'!E2, and copy down:

```
=IFNA(QUERY(
   QUERY(BookedAppointment!$A$2:$C$12,
     "select max(A), C group by C order by max(A) label max(A) '' ",0),
   "select Col2 where Col2 = '"& B2 &"' and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(D2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"  ,0))
```

The inner query creates a table with the latest appointment date for each email address.  The outer query then queries this table looking for a match with the  email address for a specific row in the NoShows tab.

If the max date from the appointments is less than or equal the no-show date for that email address in the no-shows list, record that email address.

Note I used dates from column A from BookedAppointments as the "booked date" - change this if necessary.  I also added more rows of test data.
I haven't tried to make it work yet as an ArrayFormula.

Your cell in Summary!G6 just needs a COUNTA of the column in NoShows (or wherever you put the above formula) to give a number.  Some filtering by date will be needed, if you want monthly counts.

Let me know if this helps.  I haven't added error checking, etc., unless you want to provide more than two rows of sample data.